# VSFTPD: The data connection could not be established: ETIMEDOUT - Connection attempt timed out

Tags: ftp, ubuntu-18.04, vsftpd

On July 7, our web server was dead.  We restarted it and found that it received a Kernel 41 error, but this is not our problem right now.

We have three machines on that server, one with Windows (and it works perfectly fine), second is a Gateway with CentOS and that one works too. The third machine is the issue, with Ubuntu 18.4 and FTP.

After reboot our FTP server runs `ufw`, I closed\stopped it, so now we can connect to FTP, but not always.

FileZilla does not work properly with it, there is always an `ETIMEOUT, 425 failed to establish connection`, and cannot get a list.
I double checked the firewall (on the Gateway and on FTP) was turned off, on the Gateway I checked iptables and there are ACCEPT ALL rules.

There is our vsftpd.conf:

```
listen=YES

pasv_enable=YES

pasv_min_port=62000

pasv_max_port=65535

port_enable=YES

anonymous_enable=YES

no_anon_password=YES

anon_root=/home/ftpadmin

local_enable=YES

#local_umask=022 #local_root=/home/ftpadmin

write_enable=YES

listen_port=2121

connect_from_port_20=YES

chmod_enable=YES

chroot_local_user=YES

allow_writeable_chroot=YES

passwd_chroot_enable=YES

ascii_upload_enable=YES

ascii_download_enable=YES

pasv_adress=xx.x.xxx.xxx

pasv_addr_resolve=NO

dirlist_enable=NO

user_config_dir=/etc/vsftd_conf_dir
```

> FileZilla Error:
> Respond:    227 Entering Passive Mode (46,4,134,230,252,52).
> Command:    LIST
> Error:  The data connection could not be established: ETIMEDOUT - Connection
> attempt timed out

`tracert` packets got stuck only on the FTP server, they got past the gateway, so I presume there is only problem in FTP, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can have multiple causes but, when I see your configuration I immediately will give you the following suggestion:

Change `dirlist_enable=NO` to `dirlist_enable=YES`

Furthermore make sure to improve logging with adding the following lines to your vsftpd.conf:

```
xferlog_enable=YES
log_ftp_protocol=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/ftp/xferlog
```

Also make sure to check /var/log/vsftpd.log for errors.